# PhpStorm autocompletes my class but I get Class not found in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, phpstorm

I've added my classes normally in Laravel below `app` directory. Today, when I added an API client that has a directory structure I can't make a class recognized in Laravel PSR-4 default structure.

My API client directory structure is:

```
app -- MySubdirectory -- Partners +
                                  |- Partner1
                                  |- Partner2 +
                                              |- Includes -- (other subdirectories)
                                              |- Version -- (other subdirectories)
                                              |- ApiClient.php
```

Now, I've created a model MyModel that resides below app.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    /**
     */
    protected $api;

    /**
     * Returns MyModel API Client connected to the API.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // ApiClient is not recognized thought PhpStorm do recognized.
        $this->api = \ApiClient::factory(PROTOCOL_JSON, VERSION_DEFAULT);

        $credentials = json_decode(OtherModel::where('name', 'some_name')->configuration);

        $this->api->setConnectId($credentials['connect_id']);
        $this->api->setSecretKey($credentials['secret_key']);
    }
}
```

Well, when I've wrote MyModel in line

```
$this->api = \ApiClient::factory(PROTOCOL_JSON, VERSION_DEFAULT);
```

PhpStorm suggested that class, apparently recognizing an autoloaded class.

But when I run the script I get error:

```
FatalThrowableError in MyModel.php line 20: 
Class 'ApiClient' not found
```

Ok, maybe some problem with `composer autoload` - even until now other classes that I've been created where automatically recognized by `PHP`.

So, I ran `composer dump-autoload -o` and verified `autoload_classmap.php` file and really all other subdirectories/classes below `app` directory are recognized, minus `MySubdirectory` and other subdirectories and classes below `MySubdirectory`.

My composer.json file has the basic autoload section:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

So, why running `composer dump-autoload` can't catch `MySubdirectory` and other subdirectories and classes below that?

And why PhpStorm does catch `ApiClient.php`?

Comment: Need more info. How's your `ApiClient` class is defined? What namespace it used? etc. But in general -- IDE autocompletes class names regardless of its location (even if it's located in a wrong folder).

Comment: Oops, thanks @LazyOne, you've made see the grain one span in front of me :). Bad definition of namespace in ApiClient. I've been downladed the package (an old one) and have not corrected namespace classes to conform to PSR-4 Laravel namespace structure.